# parse_str adds underscore to index and appends value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have an ajax call which sends data like this:

```
$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:URL
    data:{'fexx': $('#form').serialize()},
    ....
```

And to parse that data in php controller (i'm using Codeigniter) I recieve it like this:

```
parse_str($this->input->post('fexx'), $arr);
```

When I print the content of $arr it brings info like this:

```
Array
(
    [message_hello] => 
    [hel] => 
)
```

Instead of showing it like this:

```
Array
(
    [message] => hello
    [help] => 0
)
```

Do you know the reason for this behavior?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing methods here. If you serialize the form data then you don't supply it in key value pairs. Serialize does that for you.

```
data:{'fexx': $('#form').serialize()},
```

Try this and modify your php to suit, or remove the serialize and specify each key => value individually

```
data: $('#form').serialize(),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I know that I can do that, but I also want to add another values because that "fexx" index let me save some info directly.

Comment: If you just serialize and submit all the form data without fexx then it will be in available in the $_POST array as key value pairs